# Flask/WTForms - how can I make a form inline?

Tags: flask, wtforms

Here is the code:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"></legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      ... form fields here ...
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group-submit">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-primary") }}
  </div>
</form>
```

I am not sure how to make this field inline...bootstrap docs say to set class to `.form-inline` but that is not working here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, I will show you the use of `form-inline` to align fields horizontally:

Suppose we have a form `login_form`, which is used in the view function `login`, that in turn renders the HTML file `login.html`

**The form model:**

```
class login_form(FlaskForm):
    some_hiden_field = HiddenField()
    username = StringField('User Name :', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password :', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit_btn = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**The view function:**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['Get', 'post'])
def login():
    # some code
    my_form = login_form()
    # some code
    return render_template('login.html', form=my_form)
```

**login.html:**

```
{% extends "mybase.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block page_content %}

<form class="form-inline"  method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.username.label }} {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password(class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit_btn(class="btn btn-default") }}
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Finnally, as you know, in the above HTML code if you replace `<form class="form-inline"  method="POST">` with `<form method="POST">` you will get the vertical alignment style.

*I will add more clarification based on the comments below.*

```
import Flask-Bootstrap
import Flask-WTF
```

Take them copy and paste

**Imports collection**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for, flash, request

from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

import wtforms

from wtforms import StringField, FloatField, SubmitField, IntegerField, TextAreaField, DateField, DateTimeField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SelectField, FileField, HiddenField, Field, FieldList, FormField, Form

from wtforms.validators import Optional, NumberRange, DataRequired, Length, Email, Regexp
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will accept the answer when I get home and am able to test it out

Comment: Thanks, looking for your comments.

Comment: Hi, for the line `{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}` I'm getting that it can't find the file. Is there a particular package I need to import into the view function python file?

Comment: Edit: I added `import flask_bootstrap` although the error is still there

Comment: Did you `import Flask-WTF` ? in addition to `import Flask-Bootstrap` not `flask_bootstrap`

Comment: ```from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect

from forms import <name of form>

from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import flask_wtf```

If I use Flask-WTF and Flask-Bootstrap I get the error `invalid syntax` even though I have already used pip install for these 2 packages successfully

Comment: I have added imports collection copied from one of my systems.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the imports - it seems to not produce the not found error (after I reinstalled flask bootstrap as well) although form is still not inline. Anyway I accepted the answer because it probably is some problem with my environment/computer and not the code

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am anxious to discover why it is still not inline. it will be nice if you publish the HTML file in https://codepen.io and send the link in the comments, so we can see if there are other things - Also do you see all the fields on the browser?

Comment: in your  htm, remove  `<fieldset class="form-group">` and its `</fieldset>`,
    `<legend class="border-bottom mb-4"></legend>` and '(class="form-control-label")' from all labels to become like `{{ form.median_grade.label }}`, then test, if it succeed to become in line, start to add one by one of the items we removed to discover, which one generates the problem - waiting for the results - welcome